# Add @Html.TextBox value from ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Im using MVC 3 asp.net

How can I add an item from `ViewBag` to `html.TextBox` like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtName",@ViewBag.Parameters.Name)
```

I tried this too:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtName","@(ViewBag.Parameters.Name)")
```

nothing seems to work.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A View with just

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Html.TextBox("txtTitle", (string)ViewBag.Title)
```

works fine with me (notice the cast of the viewbag data to string because Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched.) also you will obviously have to change ViewBag.Title to your property

Comment: great the (string) fixed everything and i found another way to do what I wanted, like this: <input type="text" name="txtName" value="@(ViewBag.Parameters.Name)" />

Comment: In regards to your last comment, you are not making a use of MVC framework and HTML helpers. Yes it has a learning curve and yes it's easier to hack some HTML, pull value from view bag and it all works, but this is not what it was intended for. Please consider using HTML helpers.

Comment: I was using an @Html.ActionLink(ViewBag...  but I had to change it to @Html.ActionLink((string)ViewBag...   The casting was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This will work: `@Html.TextBox("txtName",ViewBag.Parameters.Name)` assuming that 
ViewBag.Parameters.Name has a value

Just to elaborate, you are using @ symbol twice, which doesn't make sense.

Good luck

Comment: : CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'TextBox' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: @Html.TextBox("txtName",ViewBag.Parameters.Name) and it give compilation error