# Can't use @ViewBag inside @Html.textbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I want to set the value of a text box to a `ViewBag` item. Why doesn't the code below work?

```
@Html.TextBox("UName", @ViewBag.UName)
```

Comment: I found the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190682/add-html-textbox-value-from-viewbag

Comment: @Aparn Is it helpful link?

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.TextBox("UName", (string)ViewBag.UName)
```