# How to add ViewBag property as html class attribute properly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this line:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Discounts", "ListDiscounts", "Product", null, new { @class = ViewBag.Discount })
```

The ListDiscounts is:

```
    public ViewResult ListDiscounts(int nrProducts = 5)
    {
        ViewBag.Discount = "selected";
        ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel
        {
            Products = repository.Products
            .Where(p => p.Discount != false)
            .Take(nrProducts)
        };

        return View(model); 
    }
```

The View that renders the Menu (where my separate Discounts will also be)

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@Html.ActionLink("Home", "List", "Product")



@foreach (var link in Model) { 
@Html.RouteLink(link, new
{
  controller = "Product",
  action = "List",
  category = link,
  page = 1
},
new
{
    @class = link == ViewBag.SelectedCategory ? "selected" : null,        
}) 
}
```

ListDiscounts.cshtml

```
@model Sportsstore.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "ListDiscounts";
}

<h2>Discounts available</h2>

@foreach (var p in Model.Products)
{
Html.RenderPartial("ProductSummary", p);
}
```

I'm trying to add the selected class to my 'a' element in a view but this doesn't work. The ViewBag property remains empty when I click on that Discounts link.

The View associated with ListDiscounts is not the one where that ActionLink line is from (they're separate with the one that has it being a Partial View) but from what I understand ViewBag features have some sort of a global state so this should work?

Any ideas on what is wrong here?

EDIT: Using MVC 4

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add @Html.TextBox value from ViewBag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190682/add-html-textbox-value-from-viewbag)

Comment: I have two distinct views here with a diffent html helper method so it's not the same question. I tried those answers btw and they don't work, they're for MVC 3 too.

Comment: You never state which version of MVC you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is something you are not showing us that is the problem. Perhaps you only populated the ViewBag in your post method but not your get method. I created a test application that mocks your app very closely and it works fine.

**Controller**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Discount = "selected";
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Index(int nrProducts = 5)
        {
            var model = new ProductsListViewModel{Products = "stuff"};
            ViewBag.Discount = "selected";
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.ProductsListViewModel


@Html.ActionLink("Discounts", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = ViewBag.Discount })
@{ Html.RenderPartial("ViewPage1");}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

**Partial**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Discounts", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = ViewBag.Discount })
```

When I view the source both links have the class I expected. Also after I click on the link they have the class expected. Thus I believe you are not populating the view bag either on the Get and/or the Post controller method

Comment: If I put that attribute on the method that is routed to with that link it crashes and it says that something might've been modified etc.. I don't use the post attribute in most of the methods where I use the ViewBag, is this wrong. It's mostly because that info is just for navigation. I can provide further details of course, the basic idea is that I have a Product controller that does a Listing for a certain type of products and that is triggered by a menu item, that menu item is not part of my regular nav menu items that I pass to a View in a view model...

Comment: this one is singular so I can't justify using that. I'm definitely missing something but I don't know what it is, do I have to post that action link in both views?, wouldn't it be picked up by the layout view that is on all pages?

Comment: You don't have to post it on both views. I simply did it to illustrate that it is working in both my partial and my normal view. 

I also find it strange that it crashes when you add the [HttpPost} method. It surely should not. Can you perhaps update your question with your view controller. As well as all the code for your views (layout and ListDiscounts)

Comment: Updated, I think the problem might be that the ViewBag is being reset on each request...

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you have value in the viewbag property instead of 
`@class = ViewBag.Discount` try 
`@class = @ViewBag.Discount` and see if it works

Comment: I've tried with other properties that I know should be there and it doesn't work as well. So apparently when it reaches that view the ViewBag is empty. I thought that was the whole point of having the ViewBag in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You just try the below code. Change the Viewbag name and try.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Discounts", "ListDiscounts", "Product", null, new { @class = ViewBag.CssDiscount })

public ViewResult ListDiscounts(int nrProducts = 5)
{
    ViewBag.CssDiscount = "selected";
    ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel
    {
        Products = repository.Products
        .Where(p => p.Discount != false)
        .Take(nrProducts)
    };

    return View(model); 
}
```